# Possible to add method to prototype and to have 'this' with the correct type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to add to a prototype (incidentally, a class created with TypeScript). So I have something like this:

```
declare module "./MyClass" {
    interface MyClass {
        myNewMethod();
    }
}

MyClass.prototype.myNewMethod = function() {

    let foo = this; // TypeScript doesn't pick up on foo being of type MyClass :-(

}
```

Unfortunately, TypeScript doesn't pick up on which type `this` is. Of course, I could just declare `foo` manually. But I'd rather not create an additional variable simply to overcome the TypeScript problem.

Is it possible?

Comment: You should take a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function

Comment: @TobiasS. Just did. doesn't seem to mention the case above. And TypeScript does not infer this in the situation above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand were you're declaring your class. In either case, this code actually does work:

```js
class MyClass {
  myNewMethod() {}
}

MyClass.prototype.myNewMethod = function f() {
  const foo = this // foo is correctly typed to MyClass
}
```

[Link to typescript playground (using typescript 4.7.4)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1oFt4DkBTAd1kIBcALAewBMAKASnQF8M2MFlIIA6ABwBO1ciPj9CvPEVIUataAF5oAMwCuAO2DkAltQ2qm6LNGD6I5VdWpLoVHRBMrrUgiTJU67DEA)

Comment: Strange, it does not seem to work with a separate file using the declare module syntax, which is what I need.